# Is parallel req/rep over one connection supported by nng (nanomsg-next-generation)?

Tags: parallel-processing, nanomsg

I write a multithreaded application and would like to send and receive messages (RPC like) in parallel. Both client and server should be able to send requests.

Is this possible with nng? With only one connection, or do I need to set up two connections?
Is nng threadsafe in that regard?

Can you point me to an example?

Thanks in advance!